# shutting down kvm for creating a backup image

Tags: shutdown, kvm

I am trying to shutdown a kvm on a centos using `virsh shutdown vm1` command. I checked to see if the ACPI  feature is present in the specification xml using `virsh dumpxml vm1 | grep -F acpi` and it is. What am I missing here? I don't want to force shutdown the vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `acpid` daemon process must be running in the VM guest or it will not respond to the request from the hypervisor.

From inside the guest:

```
service acpid status
```

should return the running acpid.  If it does not try:

```
sudo yum install acpid
sudo chkconfig acpid on
sudo service acpid start
```

Comment: I did check the status of `acpid` daemon and it is running.